# Why are the morphisms of the category of sets functions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

Why are the morphisms of the category of sets functions?
Shouldn't the morphisms take an object in a category and turn it into another object of the category, i.e. map Set to Set. I don't understand how e.g.
$f(x)=x^2$
is a map from a set to a set.

If the morphism had been the image of a set under a function it would make more sense to me.

Comment: It seems like you're conflating a *functor* from Set to Set with an *arrow* within Set (i.e. a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ for sets $A$ and $B$)

Comment: Your function $x\mapsto x^2$ maps the set of real numbers into the set of real numbers. It also maps the set of real numbers onto the set of non-negative real numbers. It also maps $\{0,1\}$ onto itself. So there are plenty of maps of sets (also known as morphisms in the category of sets) given by this formula $x^2$.

Comment: @Emil Well, a commutative diagram could include either - but most likely, what you encountered was a diagram in which the letters represented sets.

Comment: @Andreas: That should be an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> take an object in a category and turn it into another object of the category

This is what is called a [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor).

A morphism is (more or less) exactly a generalization of functions between sets. One function corresponds to one morphism / arrow.

Your example $f(x) = x^2$ might be considered as a morphism $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Sometimes we also write $f \in Hom(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ or $f \in Mor(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$, but those are just different notations for the same thing.

Morphisms are one of the building blocks of categories. Each category $C$ as some objects $O \in Ob(C)$, and for each pair of objects $O, P \in Ob(C)$, there is a set of morphisms $Mor(O, P)$.

Does that make something more clear?

Comment: As I wrote on the other answer, I think that the interpretation is just a naive one. And arrow between two objects is a way of "moving" from one object to another. It's not *that* far fetched to think about a morphism as something turning one object into another.

Comment: A little bit, will I run into trouble if I think of morphisms as transforming elements in an object to another element in another object, If i study another category than Set?

Comment: @Emil: The point in category theory is that objects don't really have elements in the way you think about them as concrete sets or so. From a category theoretic point of view, all singletons are equally "the same".

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand how e.g. $f(x)=x^2$ is a map from a set to a set.

In fact it is a map from a set to a set: you haven't given a precise definition of the function, so there are multiple options what the sets are, but $f$ may, e.g., map from the domain $\mathbb R$ (the set of all real numbers) to the codomain $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ (the set of all nonnegative real numbers). Then, in the category of sets, $f$ would constitute a morphism between the objects $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$.

In this context, you probably want to be thinking of functions as rules taking an input value from one set and returning an output value from another set.

Comment: Sorry if I am unclear, I meant for me $x\mapsto x^2$ is a map between elements in the set of reals, not a map of subsets of reals to subsets of reals.

Comment: @Emil In that case, it's a morphism from the set $\mathbb R$ to itself.

Comment: thank you for your answer with explicit example. I think I understand the lingo now. The objects are subsets and the morphisms are maps with the source as domain and target as codomain. I thought of the morphisms as $\mapsto$ but should have thought of $\to$.

Comment: @Emil The objects in the category of sets are _sets_ (these sets might be subsets of bigger sets, but there's no reason to think of them as subsets). Otherwise you got it!

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the morphisms take an object in a category and turn it into another object of the category

No, what makes you think so? Are you perhaps confusing *morphisms* with *functors*?

Morphism is just an arrow between two objects. Objects in set category are just sets. If $A,B$ are two sets then what would be an arrow $A\to B$? The natural choice is a function.

Comment: I think that the interpretation is just a naive one. And arrow between two objects is a way of "moving" from one object to another. It's not *that* far fetched to think about a morphism as something turning one object into another.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's the first time I've ever heard anyone saying "arrow is a way of moving". That's just wrong on so many levels. Seriously, no.

Comment: I think you're being particularly obtuse about the choice of terminology. And I understand, I would be too if someone were to say something about set theory with completely wrong ideas. But not being particularly picky about category theory, I'm just offering a naive and less-educated way of seeing morphisms. Especially when you notice that at first *all* morphisms are given by some sort of functions (continuous functions, homomorphisms, etc.), and functions can be seen as a way of "moving" from one set to another.

Comment: @freakish That was an exceptionally unhelpful comment. Certainly, the underlying metaphor of depicting a morphism by an arrow is one of motion beginning at the domain and ending at the codomain. It's not clear to me what harm noting this metaphor is likely to cause.

Comment: @KevinCarlson have you ever seen an arrow that doesn't move? Or have you ever seen a directed graph with arrows? Where is the movement there? The only unhelpful thing is to force useless metaphors.

Comment: Btw the word "arrow" is a standard nomenclature in the category theory and other parts of maths (eg directed graphs). Arguing against is just silly.